# Nestable2- How to prevent child node to dragged in another parent node?

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-nestable

[image]

Hello,
I have used nestable2, I want to prevent child node not to dragged in another parent node. It should be dragged in its parent node only.

I have used this method of nestable2 to get source and destination. I want to put validation that child node should not dragged to another parent. it should dragged in its parent.
I have applied below method, but it is not giving me destinationtype, Please suggest help

```
  $('#nestable').nestable({
        beforeDragStop: function(l,e, p){
            // l is the main container
            // e is the element that was moved
            // p is the place where element was moved.
                var sourcetype = $(e).data('type');//field
                var destinationtype = $(p).data('type');//field
                var sourcegroupid = $(e).data('groupid');//5
                var destinationgroupid = $(p).data('groupid');//5
                if (sourcetype == 'field' && destinationtype == 'field') {

                    if (sourcegroupid == destinationgroupid)//suppose 5=5
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Solved the problem by assigning type in ol too. Because i was trying to drag child to another ol list so i have to give same type.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to let you know that adding "data-type" to the ol element was a great logic I was missing for my own personalized nestable2 istance :D

This is my code that I used to allow children in root to only move inside main root and all their children can only move between "them". In short: 1st level elements stays on 1st level and 2nd level elements stays on 2nd level.

```
    beforeDragStop: function(l,e, p){
    var type = $(e).data('type');
    var type2 = $(p).data('type');

    if(type == 'root')
    {
        if(type2 != 'rooter')
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    else if(type == 'child')
    {
        if(type2 == 'rooter')
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```